# jquery mobile phonegap: page or element still in memory?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an issue I'm unable to solve.

In the page page2.html:

```html
<span id="bubbledescspec">no content yet</span>
```

Now, dynamically from another page I go to page2.html through `$.mobile.changePage("page2.html")`, with a function called when 'deviceready' and 'init' are fired for the page2.html page.
This function contains the following code:

```js
alert($("#bubbledescspec").text());
$("#bubbledescspec").text(unescape(desc));
alert($("#bubbledescspec").text());
```

Now: the `alert()` output is ALWAYS correct ("no content yet", value of desc), but the text that I see in the bubbledescspec element SOMETIMES changes accordingly, SOMETIMES doesn't change. This is why I was thinking that another element, same ID, is changed in place of the one that I want to change.

I'm obviously sure that that ID is not duplicated (`grep -R` on the project's root directory).

I don't know when/why this happens so I'm not able to reproduce the issue.

I just want to add that I don't have errors in the javascript code and the HTML is validated.
The OS is Android 4.2.2.

Any tips?

Thanks.

EDIT 1: other information. Let's say that I am in the situation when the problem occurred. If I go in the landscape mode (and from that moment in every orientation), the information is correct in the `<span>`!

Comment: Check if this solves your problem `$.mobile.changePage("page2.html", { reloadPage: true })`

Comment: Thanks Omar for the reply, sadly it doesn't work.
For now I've solved doing A LOT of operations in the JS: calling `.empty()` on the container div, creating a new element with `$("<span>")`, adding the content to the span and then adding it to the containing div with `.append()`.
For now this solution seems to work but it introduces an overhead that I would like to avoid, but without avoiding the caching/AJAX loading mechanism.

Comment: Where are you adding the bubble?

Comment: It's a normal div with an ID and a class: `<div id="scorevaluespec" class="bubble"><span id="bubbledescspec">no content yet</span></div>`. The parent of that div is only `<div data-role="content">`

Comment: This is weird. You load content into this div via Ajax dynamically?

Comment: After you load your contents dynamically, try `$('[data-role=content]').trigger('create');`

Comment: A friend tipped me to try to and force a reflow and indeed doing `var foo = $("#bubbledescspec").offset().top` after changing the text makes the issue disappear...I have to investigate better but a very close deadline doesn't let me to do it right now. I think that your last solution works, too, because it will "refresh" the content of the content data-role. For now thank you very much Omar, I will update this in some days!